# Get video duration of video stored in SharePoint library via Power Automate or Power Apps

Tags: video, sharepoint, metadata, powerapps, power-automate

I have a SharePoint Document Library containing videos being used in Power Apps, and would like to expose the duration of those videos through the app. Is there any way for me to get that property of the videos, either through Power Apps directly or upstream via a Power Automate flow when the video is first uploaded? Thanks.

Edit: using Power Automate, I've already tried using the Get file properties, Get file metadata, and Get file content actions (via the SharePoint connector), but none of their responses include the video duration. Yet if I manually browse to the "Details" of a video in my Document Library, then the video duration is listed right there, suggesting that it *should* be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Length (seconds)` column doesn't exist by default in typical `Lists`. I was able to find it by selecting an `Assets Library`.

[image]

By selecting `Views` then `All assets` I can see it in the list. It was not pre-populated for me, I had to add a value myself.

[image]

Using the `Sharepoint Get File Properties` Action I was able to get it.

**Note:** `Length` column is not part of the *body* of the action, but it is available as Dynamic Content as shown here:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps